# CakePHP: Trackable Behavior with associated models

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to use trackable behavior in CakePHP but with associated models.

I've taken [TrackableBehavior as a Model Behavior from Croogo](https://github.com/rchavik/croogo/blob/1.6/Croogo/Model/Behavior/TrackableBehavior.php) which is based upon [a plugin from Jose Gonzalez](https://github.com/josegonzalez/trackable-behavior).

It works like a charm, but I'm trying to find a way to make it work properly when the data of the child/associated model are returned in a view of the "parent" model.

The associations are:

- Clients hasMany Notes
- Notes belongTo Clients

To be more clear: Both Models use Trackable Behavior. In the Clients "view" view ( ugh ) I list **all the notes that are owned by the Client**. I'd like Trackable Behavior to return the trackable records ( created_by / modified_by ) for each note that is listed, yet it only returns the Trackable Array for the parent model ( Clients ).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit embarrassing. It was as simple as adding this before using the find() method

```
$this->Model->recursive = 2;
```

so CakePHP would go a level deeper to fetch the associated data for each item.